# Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock() must be an instance of ...\FormView, instance of ...\Form given

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

Whole error is missiong namespace **Symfony\Component\Form** which is replaced with 3 dots, due to title maximum characters.

So, I am following the steps, that are presented in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes) and I'm unable to find source of the error I'm getting. If anyone could help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here is the method from my **AuthController**

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="registrationPage")
 */
public function showRegistrationPage(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('auth/register.html.twig', [
        'register_form' => $this->createForm(RegisterType::class, (new UserInformation()))
    ]);
}
```

And here is the method, where I declare the form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstname', TextType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']])
        ->add('secondname', TextType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']])
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']])
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']])
        ->add('password_confirmation', PasswordType::class, [
            'label' => 'Confirm Password',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
            'mapped' =>false
        ])
        ->add('Register', SubmitType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']]);

}
```

Comment: You're missing `$form->createView()`, check out https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="registrationPage")
 */
public function showRegistrationPage(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(RegisterType::class, (new UserInformation()));

    return $this->render('auth/register.html.twig', [
        'register_form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#building-the-form

Comment: An explanation is always helpful, without it in this answer I have to go back and forth with the question's code to find differences and work out what the fix was :(

Answer (score 5):

the missing part was createView() method

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="registrationPage")
 */
public function showRegistrationPage(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('auth/register.html.twig', [
        'register_form' => $this->createForm(RegisterType::class, (new UserInformation()))->createView()
    ]);
}
```